# turtlebot imu installation

Tags: imu, navigation, odom-combined, gyro, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently using turtlebot kobuki base with hydro on ubuntu 12.04. With reference to this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12267/publishing-and-subscribing-gyro-msgs-in-a-turtlebot/), would like to ask where can i edit the `has_gyro parameter`?

Another question, can I just use `robot_pose_ekf` to subcribe to my new imu data and do the gmapping using the `odom_combined`?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135331/turtlebot-imu-installation/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding your first question, Kobuki has a built-in gyro. The gryo is used to determine the robot's rotation, since it is much more reliable then using the wheels' encoder output difference.

If you like to disable the usage of the gyro for odometry, set the `use_imu_heading` to `false` in `kobuki_node/param/base.yaml` (https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/blob/hydro-devel/kobuki_node/param/base.yaml).

And regarding your second question, yes, you can use `robot_pose_ekf` to use the data from your extra gyro for gmapping. Just make sure your remap the topics accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-03-05**:
noted, thanks for your answer

**Comment by [Loneflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24028/loneflyer/) on 2015-10-19**:
How would you do the same for a Create base?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2015-12-08**:
The Create 1 did not have a gyro built in. So the TurtleBot kit was sold with an external gyro. With this set-up you would need to fuse the odometry data from the Create base with the gyro data using tools like robot_pose_ekf. Don't know what the new Create 2 comes with ...